# Efficient serialization and deserialization of a hash map using the allocator

Tags: c++, serialization, deserialization, allocation, std

Is there a simple way to use a custom allocator (or, better yet, by configuring a standard allocator) with an unordered hash map or multimap in C++ so that the keys, values, and bucket structure are always kept in contiguous memory in a relatively packed form?

If so, can such an allocator then be used to save and restore the map without the explicit serialization requirement of iterating through the keys and then restoring by inserting?

If not, is there another way to serialize and deserialize a hash map that does not necessitate rehashing each key during deserialization?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a simple way to use a custom allocator

Yes

> (or, better yet, by configuring a standard allocator)

No

> with an unordered hash map or multimap in C++ so that the keys, values, and bucket structure are always kept in contiguous memory in a relatively packed form?

Yes

> If so, can such an allocator then be used to save and restore the map without the explicit serialization requirement of iterating through the keys and then restoring by inserting?

No, because between two runs of the program, the standard says you cannot make the assumption that the hashes will be the same.

But there is a false premise in your question. This is not the way to serialise an unordered_map.

> If not, is there another way to serialize and deserialize a hash map that does not necessitate rehashing each key during deserialization?

Yes - for serialisation:

```
serialise_length(archive, map.size());
for (auto const& element : map)
{
    auto const& key = element.first;
    auto const& value = element.second;
    serialise_nvp(archive, key, value);
}
```

Of course you will supply the `serialise_length()` and `serialise_nvp()` functions and the `archive` object.

For deserialisation:

```
auto map = std::unordered_map<Key, Value>();
auto length = deserialise_length(archive);
map.reserve(length);
while (length--)
{
    auto key = deserialise<Key>(archive);
    auto value = deserialise<Value>(archive);
    map.emplace(std::move(key), std::move(value));
}
```

or

```
auto map = std::unordered_map<Key, Value>();
auto length = deserialise_length(archive, length);
map.reserve(length);
while (length--)
{
    auto kv = deserialise_nvp<Key, Value>(archive);
    map.insert(std::move(kv));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inverted double linked list allocator, when previous points on previous next and next points on previous previous (imagine it in 3D , inverted lotus(not program)).